# How to aggregate + group by in scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following data:

```
val Cars_tmp = List("Cars|10|Paris|5|Type|New|3", "Cars|15|Paris|3|Type|New|5", "Cars|20|London|10|Type|New|2", "Cars|40|London|40|Type|New|1")
```

I would like to calculate the average number of cars by city.
Note that :
Cars_tmp.split('|')(6) = number of cars and Cars_tmp(2).split('|')(2) = city

I tried this :

```
          val aggregate = Cars_tmp.map(r => r.split("[|]")(6).toInt).par.aggregate((0, 0))(

          (s, r) =>(s._1 + r , s._2 + 1),

          (s,r) => (s._1 + r._1, s._2 + r._2)
          )

        val average: Float = aggregate._1.toFloat/ aggregate._2.toFloat

        println("aggregate value" + aggregate)
        println("average value" + average)
```

I have the following result:

```
aggregate value (11,4)
average value 2.75
```

This calculate the average number of cars.
How can I include the group by city (group by Cars_tmp.split('|')(2))?

Thank your for your answer.

Comment: I repeat my suggestion from your previous question. Parse that string into a **case class** so this processing becomes easier.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your answer. OK, I try that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Can you please explain with an example how you will do with case class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cars_tmp
  .map(x => {
    (x.split('|')(2), x.split('|')(6).toInt)
  })
  .groupBy { case (city, _) => city }
  .map { case (_, xs) =>
    xs
      .map(x => x._2)
      .foldLeft(0.0f) { case (acc, x) => acc + (x / xs.size.toFloat) }
  }
```

You could extract 2-tuples of (City, Number of Cars) and then use `groupBy` to create a `Map[String, List[(String, Int)]]` where the key is a city and value is a sequence of numbers of cars.

After that compute averages using `map`.

The result is:

```
List(1.5F, 4.0F)
```

Comment: `mapValues` is lazy, so this computes `xs.map(_._2).sum.toFloat / xs.length` on every access to the **Map** _(well the code is really inefficient in many ways)_

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for pointing out. Indeed, `transform` is better in this case, since `mapValues` would recompute averages on each access. I edited my answer. What would be other ways to improve performance?

Comment: @etherealyn what is `transform`? Maybe you mean `map`? - Other ways to improve performance include using `foldLeft` instead of `sum` and `size` to compute the average in one go, and transforming the **List** into a **LazyList** before the `map` + `groupBy` to perform those two operations also in one go.

Answer (score 0):

with a `df("city","nbCars")`

```
df
.groupBy("city")
.agg(
  avg(col("nbCars")).as("average_nb_cars")
)
```

check avg aggregate function : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

scala doc : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#avg(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I am working only in Scala and I am not using Spark. Have you got an idea using only Scala ?

Comment: this is scala.  if you dont use spark why you tag with apache-spark ?

Comment: I prefer to do it full Scala. But I don't know if aggregation is possible with Scala and If I have to use Spark. That's why I tag it with Spark also to have other ideas.

Comment: Moreover I have a List and not a DataFrame. First I have to convert the List to DataFrame. val a = sc.parallelize(Cars_tmp)                                                                                 val b = a.map(x => x.split('|')).toDF.show(false)  b.printSchema.      I have an array of element in the dataframe and it's not that easy to do the aggreation as mentioned on your solution.